# VB.net multiple DGV's in dataset

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I am trying to make a XML file to save project data. putting in the data from 1 DGV works, but when I try to add another table to the data set the first one gets overwritten and all I get is the table column headers of the second DGV in the XML file. So I want to know how to get data from multiple DGV in one XML file? Also need to add some textbox data to the same file. this is the code I am currently using:

```vb
Public Class Dimensioneringsapp

'data sets voor het opslaan en openen van data
Dim path As String
Dim SaveData As DataSet


   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    SaveData = CreateDatasetTable(Rekenwaardes, "Reken")
    SaveData = CreateDatasetTable(XYinput, "input")

End Sub

  'load
Private Sub OpenProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenProjectToolStripMenuItem.Click

    If opendialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        path = opendialog.FileName

        'voer het bestand in de tabellen
        LoadFromXMLfile(path)

    End If


End Sub

'save
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click

        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            path = saveFileDialog1.FileName

            SaveData.Clear()
            AddDataToDataSet(SaveData, Rekenwaardes, "reken")
            AddDataToDataSet(SaveData, XYinput, "input")
            SaveToXMLFile(path, SaveData)

        End If

End Sub

'Create Data set
Private Function CreateDatasetTable(g As DataGridView, t As String) As DataSet
    Dim dataset1 As New DataSet("SaveData")
    Dim table1 As New DataTable(t)

    'counter
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do While i < g.ColumnCount
        table1.Columns.Add(g.Columns(i).HeaderText)

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    dataset1.Tables.Add(table1)

    Return dataset1
End Function

Private Sub AddDataToDataSet(d As DataSet, g As DataGridView, t As String)

    'counter voor doorlopen tabel
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim c As Integer = 0

    Do While i < g.RowCount
        Do While c < g.ColumnCount 
            d.Tables(t).Rows.Add(g(c, i).Value)
            c = c + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1
        Loop

End Sub


Private Sub SaveToXMLFile(filename As String, d As DataSet)
    'd.WriteXml(filename, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
    Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(DataSet))
    Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(filename)
    ser.Serialize(writer, d)
    writer.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadFromXMLfile(filename As String)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Dim xmlSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(SaveData.GetType)
        Dim readStream As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)

        Rekenwaardes.Columns.Clear()

        SaveData = CType(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(readStream), DataSet)
        readStream.Close()
        'SaveData.ReadXml(filename, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
        Rekenwaardes.DataSource = SaveData.Tables("Reken")              
        XYinput.DataSource = SaveData.Tables("input")


    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That's really far too much code to be posting.  You really need to narrow it down to just what's relevant. You should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your main problem is that in `CreateDatasetTable` you are creating a new dataset each time you call it and then returning it, overwriting your dataset each time. You should just be managing that datatables in your `SaveData` instance, get rid of the local `dataset1` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom object that represents the data you want to save. So I would create a type that has a string property for your text data, and an array (or List, or IEnumerable) of datasets. I would then serialise that object. I would use JSON, but the method of serialisation is up to you.

```
Public Class ProjectData

    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property DataSets As New List(Of DataSet)

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DataSet designer in Visual Studio to define your tables, it will create a "strongly-typed" DataSet.  That is, a class that inherits from DataSet but already has the table schemas defined for you. This gives you other advantages like being able to access dataSet.TableName instead of dataSet.Table("TableName").

If you're not real picky about the formatting of the XML, then you can just use the ReadXml and WriteXml methods on DataSet to serialize the whole thing.

Then use a BindingSource on your DataGridViews

```
Dim bs1 As New BindingSource
bs1.DataSource = myDataSet
bs1.DataMember = "Table1"  
dgv1.DataSource = bs1

Dim bs2 As New BindingSource
bs2.DataSource = myDataSet
bs2.DataMember = "Table2"  
dgv2.DataSource = bs2
```